# Wigner-Yanase skew information

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, density-operator

I am reading Eric Carlen's paper on Trace Inequalities and Quantum Entropy.

I am currently reading about the Wigner-Yanase skew information which is defined as:

$$I_{WY}(\rho)=-\frac{1}{2} Tr([\sqrt(\rho),H]^2)=Tr(H^2\rho)-Tr\left(\sqrt(\rho)H\sqrt(\rho)H\right).$$

I don't understand how he arrives at the right most expression.
If I expand the commutator I get:

$$I_{WY}(\rho)=-\frac{1}{2} Tr\left(\sqrt(\rho)H\sqrt(\rho)H\right)-Tr\left(\sqrt(\rho)H^2\sqrt(\rho)\right)-Tr\left(H\rho H\right)+Tr\left(H\sqrt(\rho)H\rho\right).$$

It is not preassumed that $\rho$ and $H$ commute.

Answer (score 3):

Use that the trace is invariant under cyclic permutations of its arguments, i.e.

$$ \mathrm{Tr}(ABC) = \mathrm{Tr}(CAB) = \mathrm{Tr}(BCA)$$